# JS counter in DOM

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I've written a function to update the contents of an HTML element to display a counter. On pageload the counter will recieve an initial value, every five minutes the new value will be requested from the server. Over the next five minutes, the initial value will loop to the new value.

```
const increment = function(counter, newValue, timespan = 300000) {
  const currentValue = Number(counter.textContent);
  const diff = newValue - currentValue;
  const interval = timespan / diff;

  const intervalFn = setInterval(function() {
    counter.textContent++;
    if (counter.textContent == newValue) clearInterval(intervalFn);
  }, interval);
};
```

For simplicity I've left the server calls out:

```
<h1>0</h1> //html

const counter = document.querySelector("h1");
counter.textContent = 50;
increment(counter, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit strange:

> ```
> counter.textContent++;
> ```

Incrementing *text*... waaat? If you check the type of the `.textContent` property using `typeof`, it will tell you that it's a `string`.
For every increment, JavaScript has to convert the string to a number, performs the increment, and converts it back.

It would be cleaner to use a local variable to perform the increments,
and update `counter.textContent` from the updated value of that variable.
For example you already have the `currentValue` local variable, you could change that from `const` to `var`, and use that for counting.